# how can i render to the gsp view of other controller?

Tags: grails, rendering, gsp

I m new to grails,just started with a small application,

I'm searching a solution for below problem,

Can any one tell me how can i render to GSP view page of other controller from current controller view page.

With advance Thanks,
Laxmi.P

Comment: see my updated answer, where I have created one link which eventually redirecting to another controller's view page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets suppose you want to render finalView.gsp of FirstController from normalView.gsp of SecondController 
having the following structure :

```
FirstController.groovy
   finalView.gsp
SecondController.groovy
   normalView.gsp
```

normalView.gsp will have :

```
<g:link controller="SecondController" action="redirectToFirstController">Redirect to finalView.gsp </g:link>
```

Then inside your SecondController, define one action called redirectToFirstController

```
def redirectToFirstController =  {
 redirect(controller:"FirstController",action:"renderFinalView")
}
```

And inside your FirstController:

```
def renderFinalView = {
render(view:"finalView");
}
```

Comment: `renderFinalView` is completely redundant. An empty `finalView ` action would suffice.

Answer (score 16):

You can use either [`render(view: '/ctrlr/action', model: [fooInstance: foo])`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) or [`redirect(controller: 'ctrlr', action: 'action')`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) [controller dynamic methods](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#redirectsAndChaining) in your action, depending on if you need to user a model you already have, or to completely redirect to that action's logic.

If you're asking about GSP code, there is a [render tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html).

Comment: according to the grails reference, the controller parameter is not available for the render function. http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

Comment: Thanks but that is not what i want.I am in my y.gsp page of my second controller. in my y.gsp i am trying to have a link or button which should take me to my x.gsp page of my first controller.

Comment: @shifty: sorry, corrected. @Nandita - then you should update your question to be more precise.

Comment: ya its not.but how can i achieve my need..is there any other solution

Comment: WHAT is EXACTLY your need? Are you rendering it from an action code, or from GSP? Do you want to provide own model for that view, or just to redirect to the other controller's action?

Comment: I am trying to render from action code in my second controller to view which has model already.hope u r getting what i trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure but I think you have to use ModelAndView Class.

```
return new ModelAndView("/controller/view", [ model : youModel ])
```

Comment: are you looking for a link to another controller ? then you could use the g:link tag. http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Tags/link.html

Comment: why do I get a -1 here. ModelAndView class does work. (altough it was not the solution for Nandita) http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.3 Models and Views

Comment: This one worked brilliantly for me. Didn't even know it was there, thanks.