# Grails URLMapping multiple views

Tags: grails, view, gsp, url-mapping

This is a continuation to the question : [Grails multiple views implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259483/grails-multiple-views-implementation)

I am trying to combine two grails application ( 2 domains combined, 2 controllers combined, **2 views NOT able to combine)**

So, I tried various code snippets with "g:link" which are not working still.
I have two views : "index.gsp" & "pagetype.gsp". I want to display "index.gsp" first and then after clicking on a hyperlink it should go to "pagetype.gsp"
How do I do this?

I tried as follows:
Now, I went into "UrlMappings.groovy" and understood how the main index.gsp is accessed by this line :

```
"/"(view:"/index")
```

This is the default view, so I changed this to :

```
"/"(view:"/pagetype")
```

And now, **it loads the second view as the default view successfully**.

But, I want the "pagetype.gsp" to be loaded after clicking on a hyperlink so I tried :

```
"/."(view:"/pagetype")
```

And in index.gsp code :

```
<a href="/." class="myButton">Pagetype view</a>
```

But, this is not working.

All approaches/suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add link in `gsp` like:

```
<a href="pagetype">Click Here</a>
```

and update `UrlMappings`:

```
"/"(view:"/index")
"/pagetype"(view:"/pagetype")
```

assuming you have `pagetype.gsp` in parallel of `index.gsp` in views.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this worked perfectly!! I can merge x number of apps using this concept now.